# Prepared Statement with Hibernate Session and Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, prepared-statement

I have got a method with prepared statement that works with `Connection` class. How to make that i could work with Hibernate sessions?

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Users> listUsersSort(int weight, String gender, String place, int ageTo, String currentUser) {
        System.out.println(weight+gender+place+ageTo+currentUser);
        Connection dbConnection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;


        int iterator=0;
        List<Users> usersList =null;
        String selectSQL="select users.username, users.checkusr, users.password, users.name, users.enabled, users.surname, users.email, users.gender, users.age, users.weight, users.height, users.sport, users.place, users.photo from users where users.enabled = true";
        System.out.println(selectSQL);
        try {
            dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("first catch block");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (weight<40 == false) {

            String weightParam = " AND users.weight <= ?";
            selectSQL=selectSQL.concat(weightParam);
            System.out.println(selectSQL);
            try {
                preparedStatement.setInt(iterator++, weight);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("second catch block");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(selectSQL);
        }
        if (gender.isEmpty() == false) {
            String genderParam = " AND  users.gender LIKE '?'";
            selectSQL=selectSQL.concat(genderParam);
            try {
                preparedStatement.setString(iterator++, gender);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (place.isEmpty() == false) {
            String placeParam = " AND users.place LIKE '?'";
            selectSQL=selectSQL.concat(placeParam);
            try {
                preparedStatement.setString(iterator++, place);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (ageTo<40 == false) {
            String age = " AND users.age <= ?";
            selectSQL=selectSQL.concat(age);
            try {
                preparedStatement.setInt(iterator++, ageTo);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        String withoutUser=" AND users.username NOT LIKE '?'";
        selectSQL=selectSQL.concat(withoutUser);
        try {
            preparedStatement.setString(iterator++, currentUser);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("FINAL QUERY IS: " + selectSQL);
        ResultSet rs=null;
        try {
            rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            while (rs.next()) {

                String username = rs.getString("username");

                System.out.println("username : " + username);

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return usersList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this with Hibernate is to use [native queries](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch13.html). For example, if you're using the `Session` interface:

```
SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(selectSQL);
```

Comment: I have a NullPointer. Maybe you have got some example that shows session with PS?

Comment: You can take a look [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-native-sql-queries-examples/) and [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_native_sql.htm).